# Output to file with multiple methods

Tags: java, output

Is there a way to output to a file with multiple methods?  I used this technique in C++:

```
// create Scanner for input
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

// Output survey results to a file
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    // create Formatter for output
    Formatter out = new Formatter("numbers.txt");

    // store answer
    int ans;

    // ask 40 students to rate the food at the cafeteria
    // 1 is bad, 10 is good
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {

        // ensure answer is between 1 and 10
        do {
            System.out.print("Rate the food at the cafeteria between 1 (horrid) and 10 (excellent): ");
            ans = in.nextInt();

        } while(ans > 10 || ans < 0);
        // end do-while

    }   // end for

    // close file
    out.close();

}   // end method main

// Output data
public static void output(Formatter out, int num)
{
    // enter data in a file
    out.format("%d\n", num);

}   // end method output
```

It compiles, runs, creates the file, et cetera; but when I open the file, if is empty.  Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You are not calling `output()` method anywhere?

Comment: Foolish me!!!  I will change that and see if it works.

Comment: OK, so now the file contains the last input I gave it.  Why does it clear every time I call output()?

Comment: May be you have new `Formatter` instance everytime you call `output()` method. ;-)

Comment: Not true. The formatter object is only created at the top, and nowhere else.

Comment: Never mind, I had my output() call after the for loop.  I fixed it now, and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this is that `output()` writes the file, but you're never calling `output()`. Thus, the file is never written. You need to insert:

```
output(out, ans);
```

after the end of the do-while, but before the end of the for loop.

Comment: So true.  I just added that as you were posting your answer.